# JWT (JWS) - Asymmetric signing and refresh token

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, encryption-asymmetric

I'm struggling with a refresh token

1) Does the asymmetric signing of JWT tokens support the issuing of refresh tokens?

2) Why my Authorization Server is not issuing a refresh token based on the below configuration?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServiceConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain chain=new TokenEnhancerChain();
        chain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer, accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(chain)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false);
    }    


    //Assymetric Key Signing
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter=new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        try{
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            SecureRandom random=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, random);
            KeyPair keyPair=keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(jwtTokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but there's no relation between signing algorithm and refresh token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorization server optionally issues refresh token at the time of issuing access token.
Grant types authorization server might be supporting are:  `authorization_code, password, client_credentials, implicit, or refresh_token`. Spring OAuth2 Boot application by default provides support for clients for all above listed grant type flows, as long as you provide your `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` implementation then we need to specify grant types for clients by overriding `configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)` of `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` class as following example:

```
        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
            clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("your_client_id")
            .secret("your_client_secret_encoded")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials","refresh_token")  <<--- here
            .scopes("user_info")
            .redirectUris(uri_1,uri_2,uri_n);
        }
```

so you will get access token along with refresh token now.

Helpful material: [read](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server.html#oauth2-boot-authorization-server-disable)

***See solution in my 2nd comment.***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not keeping my client in in-memory but in database (MySQL). After I asked this question I tried a lot of things and realized that I am able to get refresh token in in-memory, but not when clients saved in the database. My clients are saved under "oauth_client_details" table, "authorized_grand_types" column as "authorization_code, refresh_token".
"access_token_validity"=3000, "refresh_token_validity"=6000. What may I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you use for persistence framework? So you have `ClientDetailsService` and `ClientDetails` implementations right? Can you show how you override  `Set<String> getAuthorizedGrantTypes();`  method of `ClientDetails`? or you use `BaseClientDetails` provided implementation? I suspect there should be problem with `getAuthorizedGrantTypes()` where it is not separating `"authorization_code, refresh_token". ` on comma.  I use Mybatis for persistence framework and I will add client details stored in DB too soon.

Comment: @PARO I have done some debugging and found out that you have space between comma separated grant types  in `"oauth_client_details"` table in `"authorized_grand_types"` column.  FIX: remove space so it will be changed from: `"authorization_code, refresh_token"` to `"authorization_code,refresh_token"`. This will fix your problem!

Comment: Your last answer solved my problem! Thank you very much. The problem was with space. Unfortunately, there are no definite materials or guides about OAuth tables, columns, and their properties. By the way, could you please have a look for another issue that I'm struggling with (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875333/spring-cloud-security-a-redirect-is-required-to-get-the-users-approval). It is not a JWT but a simple token.